# Could not create directory '/home/<user>/.ssh'. when run from oracle job

Tags: bash, oracle, shell

I have a simple file transfer bash script. When this script run directly fro solaris database server, it successfully execute and transfer the file to remote server. But when same script run through a Oracle job, it fails with following error message.

- I find this message in output column in all_scheduler_job_run_details table.

  ```
  "Could not create directory '/home/user/.ssh'.
  Host key verification failed.
  Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer"
  ```
- However /home/user/.ssh already present and there is password less connectivity to remote server.

  ```
  v_local_dir=/u12/dw/temp
  v_file_name=devcode_test_file
  v_remote_dir=upload
  v_usr=devcode
  v_server=sftp1.umbrella.com
  v_port=2222

  v_cmd="cd ${v_remote_dir}
  put ${v_local_dir}/${v_file_name}"

  echo "Executing sftp command"
  echo "Command is ${v_cmd}"

  echo "${v_cmd}" | sftp -oPort=${v_port} ${v_usr}@${v_server}
  ```

Oracle create program code

```
  dbms_scheduler.create_program
                  (
                  program_name=>'USER.PROG_DEVCODE',
                  program_action=> '/u12/dw/sftp_to_remote.sh',
                  program_type=>'EXECUTABLE',
                  number_of_arguments=>1, 
                  comments => 'push files',
                  enabled=>FALSE
                  ) ;

  dbms_scheduler.enable 'DW_USER_REPORT.PROG_PUSH_FILE_TO_DEVCODE');
```

Oracle create job program

```
declare

  p_job_name varchar2(500) := 'USER.JOB_PROG_DEVCODE';
  p_command varchar2(500) := 'PROG_DEVCODE';
--  p_args := ''
  p_type varchar2(500) := 'PROGRAM';
  p_wait_result number := 1;

begin


  DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB (
        p_job_name --               IN VARCHAR2,
      , p_command --program_name            IN VARCHAR2,
      , start_date => NULL
      , repeat_interval =>
      , end_date => NULL
      , job_class => 'DEFAULT_JOB_CLASS'
      , enabled => FALSE
      , auto_drop => TRUE
      , comments => NULL
      , job_style => 'REGULAR'
    );

    DBMS_SCHEDULER.set_attribute(
      p_job_name
    , 'credential_name'
    , 'USER.ORACLE_OS_CREDENTIAL'
  );

  DBMS_SCHEDULER.enable(
      p_job_name
  );

end;
```

Comment: As what user is the db job attempting to run the shell script? What are the permissions of the .ssh directory (should be 700)